# iOS: sending gifts to GameCenter friends

Tags: ios, messaging, game-center

Some iOS apps have the feature to send gifts (in game objects / collectables) to Game Center friends. Is this a feature that can be implemented using Game Center only or will this require a custom online backend?

Could a turn-based match be used for this feature? opening A turn-based match to a friend, encoding the definition of the gift-object in the message and closing the match as soon as the friend received it?

Or is there a problem with this approach?